# HTML BootStrap Navbar not displaying as expected

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I recently added a bootstrap navbar in a react app but it is not displaying properly when I switch sections eg. from the main page to the services page. I want a dark navbar to be displayed when switching pages instead

This is my HTML code for the navbar

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div className="container">
        <a className="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="assests/img/navbar-logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
            Menu <i className="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Faciltities</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Owners</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is dark nav bar showing in main page? Or is it like you want navbar color in main page and services page different?

Comment: Also, className="" isn't an attribute. I think you meant class="" :)

Answer (score 0):

just trigger the navbar color to black in a style tag...

```
<style>
.navbar-dark{
   color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: doesn't navbar-dark change the navbar to a darker color?

Comment: no u have to style it for example your navbar class name is navbar dark then <style>.navbar-dark{ color:- black}</style>@JasonSutanto

Comment: `<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <!-- Navbar content -->
</nav>` 

you want something like this to change the background of the navbar ?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a stylesheet and link it in your header.

Here is the code to include in the head. This would link in a stylesheet named "styles.css":

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>`

Within this stylesheet try this:

```
#darkNavbar{ 
    color : black 
}
```

This will make attributes with `id = "darkNavbar"` be the color black.

I've updated your code to remove the class `navbar-dark` and gave the navbar the `darkNavbar` id.

```
<nav id="darkNavbar" className="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <div className="container">
        <a className="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top"><img src="assests/img/navbar-logo.svg" alt="" /></a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
            Menu <i className="fas fa-bars ml-1"></i>
        </button>
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul className="navbar-nav text-uppercase ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Faciltities</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#team">Owners</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Give this a shot. Let me know if it's any help.